# Delete directory with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: vb.net, winscp, winscp-net

Have to questions cause can't find it:

1. How to check if directory contains anything e.g folder or files, whatever... or is it empty
2. How to remove an empty directory?
3. How to remove a directory even if there is content.

For instance for creating directory I am using below function:

```
Public Sub CreateDirectory(path As String)
    If session IsNot Nothing Then
        session.CreateDirectory(path)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Log file as [requested in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32942620/850848#comment53714227_32943176):

```
> 2015-10-05 11:11:13.010 MLST /\MainFolder 2014\ANIA
< 2015-10-05 11:11:13.104 550 MLST command failed: No such file or directory.
. 2015-10-05 11:11:13.104 Could not retrieve file information
< 2015-10-05 11:11:13.104 Script: Can't get attributes of file '\MainFolder 2014\ANIA'.
< 2015-10-05 11:11:13.104 Script: Could not retrieve file information

< 2015-10-05 11:11:13.104 MLST command failed: No such file or directory.
. 2015-10-05 11:11:13.104 Script: Failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check, if there are any files in a directory, use the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles method`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles):

```
Dim anyFile As Boolean =
    mySession.EnumerateRemoteFiles(
        path, Nothing, EnumerationOptions.MatchDirectories).Any()
```

The `Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles` is supported since WinSCP 5.9.

---

With older versions of WinSCP, list directory contents using the [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) and filter out the this (`.`) and parent (`..`) entries:

```
Dim anyFile As Boolean =
    mySession.ListDirectory(path).Files.
    Where(Function(file) Not file.IsThisDirectory And Not file.IsParentDirectory).
    Any()
```

---

To remove any directory, be it empty or not, use [`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles):

```
session.RemoveFiles(RemotePath.EscapeFileMask(path))
```